# Is it possible to get a font property (bold) of a cell using Application.TextStyles32Ex method (MS Project)?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I need to detect if the text in a cell is bold nor not on MS project.

There's no property of the cell object showing it, so I was wondering if it would not be possible to extract this information from Application.TextStyles32Ex.

Thanks for any help, even if the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but Project does not support direct reading of cell formatting like Excel. The best you can do is an "end-around-run" that examines the criteria for the bold formatting and then use that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @john-project. could you just explain (quickly) me what you mean by an "end-around-run", please? I made a google search about it, but I can't find what that is. else, your statement about not detecting the format on MS project is not completely true. ;) you can actually read the font color and the cell color using ActiveCell.FontColorEx & ActiveCell.CellColorEx respectively. but bold seems (way) harder to access.

Comment: Damien, you're right, my bad about the font and cell background color. What I mean by "end-around-run" is simply using in indirect approach. For example, if the bold font characteristic is not directly accessible, look at the criteria that created the bold. There's got to be a reason other than "just because".